# How to upload multiple images without using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to upload two images to the server with following code can any one please help me, here is my code for post data

```
- (void)uploadPath:(NSString*)path withOptions:(NSDictionary*)options withImageData1:(NSData*)data1 ofImageName1:(NSString *)imageName1 andImageData2:(NSData*)data2 ofImageName2:(NSString *)imageName2 {  
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURLString]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:90.0];

    NSString *boundary = @"-------1234567";

    [mutableRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [mutableRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];

    for(NSString *key in options)
    {
        NSString *value = [options objectForKey:key];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }   
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //*******************   Append 1st Image    ************************/

    if ([imageName1 isEqualToString:@"picture1.jpg"]) {
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture1\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",imageName1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data1]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //*******************   Append 1st Image    ************************/

    //*******************   Append 2nd Image    ************************/   

    if ([imageName2 isEqualToString:@"picture2.jpg"]) {
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture2\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",imageName2] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data2]];

    //*******************   Append 2nd Image    ************************/

        [mutableRequest setHTTPBody:postbody];
    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:mutableRequest delegate:self];
    if (self.urlConnection) {
        self.dataXml = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    self.urlConnection = nil;
    [mutableRequest release];
    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: You've not really said why you don't or can't use asihttprequest. do you have a problem with it? are you getting an error?

Comment: Hi Joel, Actually my project is not in the condition that I can change the request type. It's about to end but can't be finished only because of this 2 image upload functionality. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution to see what is wrong:

1. make a new project, using `ASIHttpRequest`
2. Get a web debugging proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)
3. Turn on Charles (or whatever), do a multi-file upload that succeeds.
   Record data from HTTP traffic to server.
4. Now run your own code.  Record that traffic. What is different from
   your traffic to the working traffic?  Makes yours IDENTICAL in all
   respects, and how can it not work?

You can also replace step (1) with a `curl` command line that uploads multiple files to a server and record that traffic, but I'm not versed enough in `curl` to say off the top of my head what that command would look like.

Comment: Thanx Kendall, I will try it and get back here.

Comment: Using Charles I can see that my code can't append the 2nd image data in the request. and if I interchange the position of 1st image and 2nd image in my code then it appends 2nd image but can't append the 1st image in the request.

Comment: Thanx @Kendall, Charles is awesome. I have to use ASIHTTPRequest but it's ok.... Thanx a lot once again.

Comment: Not sure how to help, but I hope you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSString*) nameValString: (NSDictionary*) dict {//example CHLOVA_FORM_BOUNDARY is @"aaa"
NSArray* keys = [dict allKeys];
NSString* result = [NSString string];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < [keys count]; i++) {
    result = [result stringByAppendingString:
              [@"--" stringByAppendingString:
               [CHLOVA_FORM_BOUNDARY stringByAppendingString:
                [@"\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" stringByAppendingString:
                 [[keys objectAtIndex: i] stringByAppendingString:
                  [@"\"\r\n\r\n" stringByAppendingString:
                   [[dict valueForKey: [keys objectAtIndex: i]] stringByAppendingString: @"\r\n"]]]]]]];
}

return result;
}

- (void)sendPhoto{
NSString *param = [self nameValString:dic];//dic is post info like {lat=36;lng=120;}
NSString *footer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", CHLOVA_FORM_BOUNDARY];

param = [param stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", CHLOVA_FORM_BOUNDARY]];
param = [param stringByAppendingString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pic\";filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"];

NSData *jpeg = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:_path], 0.55);
//NSLog(@"jpeg size: %d", [jpeg length]);

NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
//img one
[data appendData:[param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[data appendData:jpeg];
[data appendData:[footer dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//img two
[data appendData:[param2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[data appendData:jpeg2];
[data appendData:[footer2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", CHLOVA_FORM_BOUNDARY];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
//then do sending
}
```